# brightness bar blinking 18.04

Tags: 18.04, brightness, titlebar

I have a problem with sound bar and I don't know how to figure it out. Here is a video to see what I mean:

[See here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15qi-OYJyoP-IodDKwR3TLmvsg23cf-R8/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Looks like this issue upstream in GNOME Settings Daemon, https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/-/issues/108 - which was apparently fixed https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/-/merge_requests/14 - perhaps that fix didn't make its way into Ubuntu 18.04 yet.

Comment: You may also want to edit your question, you're modifying brightness, not sound, in the video.

Comment: So,I can't do anything.Anyway,thanks for the update.